# $http put v create - what is the difference between the data object returned from .success() in each (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Is there a fundamental difference between "`data`" variable returned from `.success()` in `$http.create v $http.put` ?

I've added "`console.log(data)`" to 2 different functions below (and included the Rails controllers for reference) so we can see the difference in output.

**Create**

```
i.create = function(item) {
    return $http.post('/items.json', item).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};

def create
    respond_with Item.create(item_params)
end
```

**Put**

```
i.edit = function(id, item) {
    return $http.put('/items/' + id + '.json', {item: item}).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};

def update
    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    item.update_attributes(item_params)
    respond_with item
end
```

The first function prints below to console, (*which includes the object*)

```
app.self-58d6f492fc5c0efae12da42ede8f7ad0257b7e5ce84e944443b2beecbb803e20.js?body=1:165
<br>
 Object {id: 22, desc: "testabc", list_id: null, created_at:
"2016-03-10T02:47:05.194Z", updated_at: "2016-03-10T02:47:05.194Z"…}
```

The second function prints below to console, (*no object*)

```
app.self-58d6f492fc5c0efae12da42ede8f7ad0257b7e5ce84e944443b2beecbb803e20.js?body=1:186
```

Both functions work and do their job. But "data" returned from the PUT does not contain the object.

Why does it happen this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no fundamental difference between the two, the only thing that makes them difference is the data response from the server. The update controller of your server might not responding json object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've included my rails controllers above for reference. Do you know why the update controller might be responding differently?

Comment: @ pandaman there is a action called upvoting  please use it and upvote instead of saying thanks .. if you got answer or  helped you need to upvote or accept that is the process .. pls use that good process ...